# How to create a responsive hover for my pictures?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I want to make a responsive hover for my pictures but it's not working...
When I add the code to hover, my images lose responsiveness.

This is my html code:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="media"> 
            <img class="media__image" src="img/06_team.png" alt="">
            <div class="media__body">
                 <h2>asfafs</h2>
                 <p>asfkasf</p>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
    .media {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.media__image { display: block; }

.media__body {
  background: rgba(41, 128, 185, 0.7);
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3.75em 3em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.media__body:hover { opacity: 1; }

.media__body:after,
.media__body:before {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  bottom: 1em;
  content: '';
  left: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s 0.2s;
  transition: 0.6s 0.2s;
}

.media__body:before {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  left: 2em;
  right: 2em;
}

.media__body:after {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  bottom: 2em;
  top: 2em;
}

.media__body:hover:after,
.media__body:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.media__body h2 { margin-top: 0; }

.media__body p { margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
```

Please help me

Comment: Please use media queries for responsive effect.

Comment: please give me an example. Thanks

Comment: Past the right code, all the `div`s in your code are not closed. Preferable create a JSFiddle. Also, read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask